# PHP Looping Javascript Just Show The First Record

Tags: javascript, php

I have a view code:

```
 <?php
      $i = 1;
      //var_dump($this->productList);
      foreach ($this->productList as $data) {
         $desc=explode(",",$data['descriptions']);
      ?>
         <tr>
             <th colspan="3">
                  <input type="hidden" id="id_pack" name="id_pack" value="<?php echo $data['package_id']; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" id="nama_pack" name="nama_pack" value="<?php echo $data['package_name']; ?>">
                  <h4 align="center" class="title-pack"><?php echo $data['package_name']; ?></h4>
             </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="dashe">
             <td>
                 <ul class="myul">
                 <?php foreach($desc as $descriptions) { ?>
                     <li class="myli"> <?php echo $descriptions; ?></li>
                 <?php } ?>
                 </ul>
             </td>
             <td>
                <h4 class="prize">
                Rp. <?php echo number_format($data['price'],2);?>
                 / month
                </h4>
            </td>
            <td>
               <p id="order" name="order" class="mybutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mymodal">Order</p>
            </td>
      </tr>
<?php
   $i++;
   }
?>
```

And this the javascript:

```
 document.getElementById("order").addEventListener("click", tampilkanHrm);
    function tampilkanHrm() {
        var pilihan=$("#nama_pack").val();
        document.getElementById("choice").innerHTML = pilihan;
        document.getElementById("pack").value = pilihan+" Package";
    }
```

the problem is, in the order button it always show the same record. Just show the first data, even i clicked other order button. Hope somebody help.

Comment: You can't assign same id for multiple elements..

Comment: ok, but how to differentiate one and another? if i used `id="order($i)"` then how i call it in javascript? @EdwinAlex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign same id for multiple elements.

So, have different ids.

```
<?php
      $i = 1;
      //var_dump($this->productList);
      foreach ($this->productList as $data) {
         $desc=explode(",",$data['descriptions']);
      ?>
         <tr>
             <th colspan="3">
                  <input type="hidden" id="id_pack<?php echo $i ?>" name="id_pack" value="<?php echo $data['package_id']; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" id="nama_pack<?php echo $i ?>" name="nama_pack" value="<?php echo $data['package_name']; ?>">
                  <h4 align="center" class="title-pack"><?php echo $data['package_name']; ?></h4>
             </th>
        </tr>
```

Similarly create buttons with different ids.

```
<td>
    <p id="<?php echo $i ?>" name="order" class="mybutton" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".mymodal">Order</p>
 </td>
```

Then change your javascript to jquery. Hope, you might also be using jquery [ understood from your code ]

```
$(".mybutton").on("click", function() {
   var identifier = $(this).attr("id");
   var pilihan=$("#nama_pack"+identifier).val();
   $("#choice").html(pilihan);
});
```

Change your code like this and check.